# Base64 encoded string to file(Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, base64, file-writing

I have a requirement where a zip file is sent to the ROR application after encoding it with Base64 encoding. I should decode it, save it as a zipfile and unzip it and do some operations. They are sending the zip file encoded data as a parameter called `zip` through POST method. Here, is what I have done in code.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'zip/zip'
require 'base64'

def get_pdf
  encoded_data = Base64.decode64(params[:zip])
  File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/zip_archive/zip_file.zip", "w") {|f| f.write encoded_data}
  unzip_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/zip_archive/zip_file.zip", "#{RAILS_ROOT}/unzipped/")
  ...(using @file_path, do stuff)
end

def unzip_file (file, destination)
  destination = File.join(destination, File.basename(file, ".zip"))
  Zip::ZipFile.open(file) { |zip_file|
    zip_file.each { |f|
      f_path=File.join(destination, f.name)
      FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path))
      zip_file.extract(f, f_path) unless File.exist?(f_path)
    }
  }
  @file_path = destination
end
```

But, I am not able to save the zip file correctly. The file after saving is giving error on the unzipping part.

```
Zip::ZipError (Zip end of central directory signature not found):
  rubyzip (0.9.4) lib/zip/zip.rb:1287:in `get_e_o_c_d'
  rubyzip (0.9.4) lib/zip/zip.rb:1235:in `read_e_o_c_d'
  rubyzip (0.9.4) lib/zip/zip.rb:1260:in `read_from_stream'
  rubyzip (0.9.4) lib/zip/zip.rb:1392:in `initialize'
  rubyzip (0.9.4) lib/zip/zip.rb:1392:in `open'
  rubyzip (0.9.4) lib/zip/zip.rb:1392:in `initialize'
  rubyzip (0.9.4) lib/zip/zip.rb:1410:in `new'
  rubyzip (0.9.4) lib/zip/zip.rb:1410:in `open'
  app/controllers/pdf_controller.rb:37:in `unzip_file'
  app/controllers/pdf_controller.rb:13:in `get_pdf'
```

When I tried to open the file outside the app also, the file was not getting opened saying

```
[/home/prince/Desktop/test_project/zip_archive/zip_file.zip]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/prince/Desktop/test_project/zip_archive/zip_file.zip or
          /home/prince/Desktop/test_project/zip_archive/zip_file.zip.zip, and cannot find /home/prince/Desktop/test_project/zip_archive/zip_file.zip.ZIP, period.
```

I tried saving the file with `File.open("..", "wb")` to write the contents in the binary mode, but then also the same error occurs. Should I do anything to the `params[:zip]` before decoding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works like a charm. The `File#open` block should properly write and close the file, you're probably just having the wrong path in there somewhere. If the `File.exists?` and the decode64 went through, you should be good.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > zip = "UEsDBAoAAAAAAKphcT4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFABwAZW1wdHlVVAkAA8/sgU3P\n7IFNdXgLAAEE9QEAAAQUAAAAUEsBAh4DCgAAAAAAqmFxPgAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAUAGAAAAAAAAAAAAKSBAAAAAGVtcHR5VVQFAAPP7IFNdXgLAAEE9QEAAAQU\nAAAAUEsFBgAAAAABAAEASwAAAD8AAAAAAA==\n"
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > File.open('test2.zip', 'wb') {|f| f.write(Base64.decode64(zip))}
 => 160 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Zip::ZipFile.open('test2.zip') {|z| z.each {|f| puts f.name}}
empty
 => [empty]
```

Comment: But I am passing the file to a block and closing the block. I have read somewhere that on closing the block the file is also closed. Anyway I will try by explicitly closing the file. Thanks...

Comment: Already edited the answer - hasty morning reply. Yes, the block will close the file. The example as I posted it works.

Comment: Not a ruby problem then because the above works in both ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 with zip-2.0.2 -- but, if you meant YOUR code still doesn't work then read my answer again - you're most likely having the wrong path in there somewhere and should do proper error handling, checking existence, filesize, etc.

Comment: it was an error from their part..they were not passing the parameter correctly...thanks..fx_ :)