# Create file Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, xamarin

I'm sending an .AAC file from an iPhone to an API in RoR. What I'm doing is read the file byte by byte in the iPhone, convert the byte[] to a Base64 String, send the string to an API and then decode the String to the array and save that byte[] to a file.
The problem is the file being created on the serve side is different from the one sent, even though I checked and the byte[] is the same on the server side, when I save byte by byte I end up with a different filesize and it's also unplayable.

This is the code I'm using

```
File.open("test.aac", 'wb' ) do |output|
plain.each_byte do | byte |
   output.print byte
   puts byte
   i=i+1
end
puts "_______"
puts i
puts "_______"
end
```

I've literally tried everything but I have no idea why it doesn't work.

This is the code that receives

```
mail=params["mail"]
archivo=params["byte"]
puts mail
puts archivo
plain=Base64.decode64(archivo);
```

variable plain has exactly the same bytes as the byte I sent from the iPhone.

This is in Xamarin:

```
byte[] info = File.ReadAllBytes (audioFilePath.Path.ToString ());
String bytesTo64 = Convert.ToBase64String (info);
```

Comment: where is the code that actually receives and decodes the file?

Comment: Updated the code Jason.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the problem was writing byte by byte. I changed the code with 
[Base64 encoded string to file(Ruby on Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337449/base64-encoded-string-to-fileruby-on-rails?rq=1)
and it worked flawlessly. This is my final code.

```
File.open('Now.aac', 'wb') { |f| 
f.write(Base64.decode64(archivo))
```

}